# TFS programatically find and use files from last build

Tags: tfs, wix

I am new to TFS. I have two builds on TFS, one is the main solution which spills out .exe files, the other a Wix installer solution that grabs files from the main solution. Right now I use a temp file folder and post/pre build events to receive/feed these .exe files.

Can I streamline this process on TFS? I'd like the installer to

1. Main solution generates a meaningful file path for each build, ideally related to build number.
2. Installer solution can find file path of the last successful build of main solution programmatically.
3. Make this file path available as a build variable or something so it knows where to grab files when building.

Comment: Make them one build.

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Did you don't want to chain the build such  as one build trigger another? Just as Daniel suggested could you make them integrate with one build definition?